# React Native. Custom ringtone and SMS notifications

Tags: audio, react-native, ringtone

Does React Native can work with an android ringtone | sms notifications sound? 
I want to intercept a standard call | sms  actions and play my own sound\voices etc. via my application.

Is it possible to do via React Native? (or maybe other tools like: Ionic 2\Apache Cordova). I checked the React Native documentation API and I didn't see anything about " standard call sound " etc.

Thanks for any help.